# When to use next-i18next or other i18n libraries?

Tags: next.js, internationalization, i18next

Sorry this may be a dumb question but I just want to make sure.

I'm trying to add some internationalization to my app and have been confused. Currently I'm Next13 (not experimental, at least not yet) to switch between two languages by just using vanilla Nextjs. However, I see a lot of people use next-i18next and it looks like a lot of set up.

Should I use this package? Or is it more for bigger projects? Would it be better to switch to the experimental Next13 with everything being SSR?

As you can see, I'm just trying to figure out what problem it solves. Maybe it makes it easier, but it seems like a decent amount of set up.

I'd appreciate any help! Thank you so much.

Answer (score 0):

The config for nextjs only handles locale-related routing, it doesn't do anything for translation logic. So you can't "switch" between two languages using vanilla nextjs, only change the locale url.
It takes a lot of setup because adding translation logic to an app without it is going to take a lot of setup. And in general multilang support adds complexity to the code.
Experimental Next13 is even worse, since it basically delegates handling the entirety of multilang logic down to userland, even routing. And going purely SSR is going to do a lot of harm, because frontend internationalization revolves around translating values known at build time. Fetching and passing them at each request is an overhead and a waste of bandwidth (although it's bigger bux for Vercel).

> As you can see, I'm just trying to figure out what problem it solves.

As the name suggests, it basically adapts `i18next` to `NextJS`. Without it you'd have to write your own logic for handling quadrillion ways nextjs renders pages and their contexts.